# How to troubleshoot 400 Axios errors in NodeJS / Nuxt / VueJS app on the web server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

We are working on a fairly simple VueJS / Nuxt app to be served using NodeJS. The app makes two API calls - one to Airtable, one to the Google Location API.

Running this on our local (Ubuntu) machines `npm run dev` & `npm run build` work as expected; we can serve the app locally either directly through the `localhost:3000` or running the NodeJS server & targeting the `/dist/` folder.

Now we're trying to make the app live on our (Ubuntu) DigitalOcean staging server but it won't work.

Running `npm run generate` (which is `nuxt generate`) returns the following error:

```
Request failed with status code 400                                   23:14:06

  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
  at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
  at Unzip.emit (node:events:390:28)
  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1340:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I'm interpreting this to mean there is an issue with one of the API calls - but how do I troubleshoot this error?

The same code runs on the same operating system on our local development machines. Why won't it compile correctly and run on the server?

My best guess is that it's not picking up one of the API keys from the `.env` file during build - but that should work as expected.

Comment: `but that should work as expected` is probably the starting point here. Double-check this one. Also, maybe try to host it on app.netlify.com/drop for debugging purposes. And finally, a simple solution would be to put some `console.log` before and after each call you're making to be sure of which ones are successful and which one are not, simple and easiest to setup as a debugging solution.

Comment: I agree with kissu, in that I would first just be logging the `.env` variables to you need to make sure that they're there. I wonder if nuxt requires a `.env.production` file or something? Or some other configuration for production

Comment: can you share the steps you took to put the application code on the droplet?

Comment: @BaronGrivet did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this resolved yet?

Comment: Having the same issue, any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will assist others. Solved the issue on my end by making environment variables accessible under store/index.js using dotenv, for some reason 'process.env.VAR_NAME' wasn't readable.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/what-are-env-files-and-how-to-use-them-in-nuxt-7f194f083e3d